# Add/Subtract time in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using xpath 2.0.

I want to add 30 minutes to the variable `$orario`.

```
  <tempi id="ID_1">
    <orario_part>09:20:00</orario_part>
    ...
  </tempi>
```

This is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
<xsl:template match="tempi">
   <xsl:variable name="orario" select="./orario_part"/>
   <xsl:variable name="totale" select="xs:time($orario)+xs:time('00:30:00')"/>
   <time>
       <xsl:value-of select="$totale"/>
   </time>
</xsl:template>
```

The following is the desired result:

```
<time>09:50:00</time>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What error does the above code give you?

Comment: XSL trasformation failed

Comment: error in XPATH 2.0 expression- type doesn't support operator-current item is '09:20:00.0' of type xs:time

Comment: You can't add two times. You need to add a time and a duration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tempi id="ID_1">
    <orario_part>09:20:00</orario_part>
</tempi>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:template match="tempi">
        <xsl:variable name="orario" select="./orario_part" />
        <xsl:variable name="totale" select="xs:time($orario)"/>
        <time>
            <xsl:value-of select="$totale +  xs:dayTimeDuration('P0DT0H30M')"/>
        </time>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives

```
<time>09:50:00</time>
```